# Does the sentence in bold uses "unless" incorectly? If yes. What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This context comes from the movie "Dr. Strangelove" by Stanley Kubrick
It's a phone call between General Ripper and Group Captain Lionel Mandrake.

"Ripper-This is general Ripper speaking.

Mandrake-Yes, sir.

Ripper- Do you recognize my voice?

Mandrake- I do, sir. Why do you ask?

Ripper- Why do you think I ask?

Mandrake- Well, I don't know, sir.
We spoke just a few moments ago
on the phone, didn't we?

Ripper-**You don't think I'd ask if you recognize my voice unless it
was pretty damned important, do you, Mandrake?**

Mandrake-**No, I don't, sir.**

Ripper-Let's see if we can stay on the ball."

I don't understand the sentence in bold. What befuddles me is the use of the word "**unless**". If the question was phrased "You don't think I'd ask if you recognize my voice **if** it was pretty damned important, do you, Mandrake?" would make sense to me albeit only if the answer Mandrake gives(No I don't sir) meant that (yes he would think that he would ask if it was important)

Does the sentence from the movie make logical sense to you guys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense.

It's equivalent to:

> I would **not** ask if you recognize my voice **if it was not** important.

Hopefully the two negatives here are clear: because it *is* important, he *will* ask.

Now rephrase the second negative as *unless*:

> I would **not** ask if you recognize my voice **unless it was** important.

Finally, transponse the first negative into the rhetorical question from the movie:

> You **don't think** I'd ask if you recognize my voice **unless it was** important, do you?

The negatives still add up to the positive: it is important, so he will ask.

Answer (score 0):

It makes logical sense. A question starting 'You don't...' expects a negative answer.

You aren't driving the car in your drunk condition, are you? The speaker is strongly implying that the right answer is 'no'.

X unless Y means 'X [only] if Y is not the case'.

'You don't think I'd do X unless Y were true?' is saying 'You are mistaken and foolish if you think I'd do X if Y were not true'

I think you are being puzzled by the double negation of 'don't think' ... and 'unless'. Consider the sentence to mean 'Do you think I would ask if you recognise my voice *if it wasn't* important?'.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was confused by the double negative. So let's see if I get it. The question(in question :)) expects a negative answer, therefore "You don't think I'd ask if you recognize my voice" the answer to this is **No** even though the answer to "unless it was pretty damned important" could be **Yes** but we answer **No** to the entire question as confirmation which includes the answers *No* for the first part, and **Yes** for the second, because the question was asked in the negative and only in this way we can confirm everything that General Ripper said. Is that correct?